# How to format a list based on its number of indexes

Tags: python, format

So I saw a program that can format a sentence with strings inside a list. That program looks like this:

```
animals = ["dog", "bear"]

safari = " I saw {} and {}

print(safari.format(*animals))
```

So I was wondering what if I had a bigger list, then I would have to put so many {} to format. That's why I wanted to create a program that adds these brackets {} based on how many strings are there in a list. The program looks like this but doesn't work:

```
animals = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "elephant", "bird", "lion", "llama", "flamingo", "cow", "whale", "shark", "fish", "bear", "pig"]

safari = "I saw "
for i in range(len(animals)):
x = " {} ".join(safari)

print(safari.format(*animals))
```

It's really simple, yet I don't understand why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it will join the elements with `{}`. You got confused how `.join` works.

Consider the following:

```
>>> a=['a','b','c']
>>> ', '.join(a)
'a, b, c'
```

It returns a string by joining the given **iterable** with the delimiter.

Similarly, that is what is happening with `'{}'.join(animals)`

```
>>> '{}'.join(a)
'a{}b{}c'
```

You can try this:

```
animals = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "elephant", "bird", "lion", "llama", "flamingo", "cow", "whale", "shark", "fish", "bear", "pig"]
new='I saw '
new+=', '.join("{}" for i in animals)

print(new.format(*animals))
```